# Display data array in combobox angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to display data in the combobox from a json object.

```
 <select ng-model="vm.datasource.currencyFormatChoice" ng-options="currencyFormatChoice as currencyFormatChoice for currencyFormatChoice in vm.datasource.currencyFormat"></select>
```

This is the json object I have. Now I want to set the displayValue into the combobox.

```
"currencyFormat": [ { "displayValue": "€ 1.000,00", "value": "{0:C2}" }, { "displayValue": "€ 1.000", "value": "{0:C0}" }, { "displayValue": "$ 1,000.00", "value": "{0:C2}" }, { "displayValue": "$ 1,000", "value": "{0:C0}" }, { "displayValue": "1.000,00", "value": "{0:N2}" }, { "displayValue": "1.000", "value": "{0:N0}" }, { "displayValue": "1,000.00", "value": "{0:N2}" }, { "displayValue": "1,000", "value": "{0:N0}" } ]
```

With the code of HTML I get [object Object] instead of $1000. How can I get the displayValue into the combobox?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick!

```
ng-options="currencyFormat as currencyFormat.displayValue for currencyFormat in vm.datasource.currencyFormat"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you take a look at the following fiddle.

```
    <div ng-app="myapp">
      <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select ng-model="modelValue" ng-options="currencyFormatChoice.displayValue for currencyFormatChoice in vm.datasource.currencyFormatChoice"></select>

      </fieldset>
    </div>

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.modelValue = {};
      $scope.vm = {
        datasource: {
          currencyFormatChoice: [{
            displayValue: "€ 1.000,00",
            value: "{0:C2}"
          }, {
            displayValue: "€ 1.000",
            value: "{0:C0}"
          }, {
            displayValue: "$ 1,000.00",
            value: "{0:C2}"
          }, {
            displayValue: "$ 1,000",
            value: "{0:C0}"
          }]
        }};
      });
```

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/223/)

Comment: Thanks for you time! I still get [object Object] in my combobox after I insert your solution.